# Comparacion entre dos Arrays JAVA

Tags: java

El ejercicio se trata sobre realizar la unión de dos arreglos de cadenas de caracteres.

Ej:

```
A={"a","b","c"}

B={"a","e"}

AB={"a","b","c","e",null}
```

El tamaño del arreglo para la unión, puede ser la suma del tamaño de los otros arreglos, por eso, puede existir valores `null` en la unión.

El código que tengo une dos Arrays pero no me devuelve `null` si están repetidos dos valores.

```java
public class Union{
    public static String[] union(String[] vec1,  String[] vec2){
        String[] vec3= new String[vec1.length+vec2.length];
        int i=0;
        
        for(i=0;i<vec1.length;i++){
            vec3[i]=vec1[i];
        }
        
        for(int j=0;j<vec2.length;j++){
           int n=0;
            if (vec1[n]!=vec2[j]){
                vec3[i]=vec2[j];
                n++;
                i++;
            }
            if(vec1[n] == vec2[j]){
                
                vec3[i]=null;
                n++;
                i++;
            }
            
            
        }
        
        return vec3;
   }
}
```

Comment: En que lugar te estas fijando si lo que queres meter esta en el arreglo final?

Comment: Pense que era necesario para que se logre entender lo que quiero hacer

Comment: Tu ejercicio dice que no tenes que ingresar repetidos.. yo te estoy preguntando, en que parte de tu codigo estas revisando si lo que ingresas es repetido?

Comment: en el ultimo if if(vec1[n] == vec2[j]){
                
                vec3[i]=null;

Comment: ahi no estas comparando que ya exista en la salida... ahi estas comparando el primero de vec1 con alguno de vec2.. lo cual no implica que ese de vec2 no sea igual a otro de vec1.... yo seguiria tu programa en un papel, para que veas lo que va haciendo....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre es:
**Primero**
Convertir los valores duplicados del vector 2  en null y copiar todos los valores del vector 1 en el vector 3

```
String[] vec3= new String[vec1.length+vec2.length];
        
for(int i=0;i<vec1.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<vec2.length;j++){
        if(vec1[i].equals(vec2[j])){
           vec2[j]=null;
        }
        vec3[i]=vec1[i];
   }        
}
```

**Segundo**
Al tener elementos null en el vector 2, copiamos los valores diferentes de null en el vector 3

```
int n=0;
for(int i=0;i<vec2.length;i++){
   if(vec2[i]!=null){               
       vec3[vec1.length+(n)]=vec2[i];
       n++;
   } 
}

return vec3;
```

**Observación**
Al comparar cadenas tienes que usar el método `equals()` en lugar de la comparación `==`

Comment: Gracias por la observación, no sabia eso.

Answer (score 7):

Una forma de realizarlos es usando HashSet, creas un HashSet para agregar los valores del Array A y B para realizar la uniòn, posteriormente inicializas un Array con la suma de la longitud de ambos array y finalmente insertas los valores

```
 String[] A={"a","b","c"};
 String[] B={"a","e"};

 //Obtiene longitud total.
 int totalLength = A.length + B.length;

 //Crea HashSet donde agrega los valores de array A y B.
 HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(); 
 set.addAll(Arrays.asList(A));
 set.addAll(Arrays.asList(B));
  
 System.out.println(totalLength);


//Inicializa con valores null
String[] myUnion = new String[totalLength];

//Agrega union de Arrays A y B a Array final.
myUnion = set.toArray(myUnion);
 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myUnion));
```

Salida:

```
[a, b, c, e, null]
```

Comment: me pa que es tarea.. si usa un hashset, no aprendera nada ;)

Comment: Si estoy aprendiendo y nunca habia usado un HashSet porque voy poco a poco, me parece interesante pero quiero saber si existe alguna forma de hacerlo como lo estaba intentando

Answer (score 4):

¡Logre hacerlo sin Hash! Obviamente lo mejor seria utilizarlos.

Se crean 2 bucle for, uno hace la primera interacción y se guarda el valor y el índice interado hasta el momento, el segundo lo que hace es recorrer todo el arreglo comprobando si hay algún valor que sea igual a ese valor guardado, pero que el indice sea diferente (obviamente), y también se comprueba si se diferencia de `null` el objeto interado ya que si no da `NullPointerException`

De esta manera, pInteraccion seria el primer bucle y sInteraccion es el segundo bucle, si se da el caso que es repetido, lo cambiamos a `null`.

```
private static String[] unir(String[] arreglo1, String[] arreglo2) {
    String[] arreglo = new String[arreglo1.length + arreglo2.length];
    
    System.arraycopy(arreglo1, 0, arreglo, 0, arreglo1.length);
    System.arraycopy(arreglo2, 0, arreglo, arreglo1.length, arreglo2.length);
    
    for (int pInteraccion = 0; pInteraccion < arreglo.length; pInteraccion++) {
        String interado = arreglo[pInteraccion];
        int indice_interado = pInteraccion;
        
        for (int sInteraccion = 0; sInteraccion < arreglo.length; sInteraccion++) {
            if(arreglo[sInteraccion] != null && sInteraccion != indice_interado) {
                if(arreglo[sInteraccion].equals(interado)) {
                    arreglo[sInteraccion] = null;   
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    return arreglo;
}
```

Yo use `System.arraycopy()` para copiar arreglo1 y arreglo2 en el arreglo de retorno, pero igual se puede copiar manualmente con un bucle for, eso es solo opcional.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] arreglo1 = {"a","b","c","a"};
    String[] arreglo2 = {"e","f","f"};
    
    String[] unidos = unir(arreglo1, arreglo2);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < unidos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(unidos[i]);
    }
    
}
```

Salida:

```
a
b
c
null
e
f
null
```

Comment: Wow muy buena logica en el codigo

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma de hacerlo

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //declaramos los arrays a unir
    String[] A = {"a","b","c"};
    String[] B = {"a","e"};
    
    //llamamos a la función unión enviado los array por parámetro y recibimos el array resultante
    String[] C = union(A, B);
    
    //bucle que recorre el array salvo el último valor del mismo
    for (int i = 0; i < (C.length - 1); i++){
        //imprime cada valor menos el último con una coma detrás
        System.out.print(C[i] + ", ");
    }
    //imprime el último valor del array
    System.out.println(C[C.length - 1]);
    
}
//método que une los array recibidos por parámetro
public static String[] union(String[] vec1,  String[] vec2){
    //declaramos dos variables de enteros con a longitud de cada array
    int nA = vec1.length;
    int nB = vec2.length;
    
    //declaramos el array que resultará de la unción de los arrays
    String[] vec3 = new String[nA + nB];
    
    //bucle que recorre el array resultado
    for (int i = 0; i < vec3.length; i++){
        //si el valor de la variable del bucle es menor que la longitud del primer array
        if (i < vec1.length){
            //añadimos los valores del primer array al array resultado
            vec3[i] = vec1[i];
        }
        //si el valor de la variable del bucle es igual o mayor a la longitud del primer array, y ...
        //el valor de la variable del bucle es menor a la suma de los dos arrys
        else if ((i >= vec1.length) && (i < (vec1.length + vec2.length))){
            //añadimos los valores del segundo aaray al array resultado
            vec3[i] = vec2[i - vec1.length];
        }
    }
    //bucle que recorre el array resultado menos un valor del mismo
    for (int i = 0; i < vec3.length - 1; i++) {
        //bucle que recorre el array resultado incrementando en 1 el valor del bucle anterior
        //de ésta forma no se comparará cada valor por si mismo
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vec3.length; j++) {
            //si el valor del array resultado en la posición del primer bucle, es equivalente
            //al valor del array resultado en la posición del segundo bucle
            if(vec3[i].equals(vec3[j])){
                //ponemos su valor a null
                vec3[j] = "null";
            }
        }
    }
    //retornamos el valor del array resultante
    return vec3;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la extensa explicación, muy completa.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera y podría unir mas arreglos solo modificando el arraycopy

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class union{

    static String[] unionSinRpetirDatos(String[]a,String[]b){
      String []ab=new String[a.length+b.length];
      System.arraycopy(a, 0, ab, 0, a.length);
      System.arraycopy(b, 0, ab, a.length, b.length);


      String[]temporal1=new String[ab.length];
      int n=0;
      int cont=0;

         Arrays.sort(ab);
         for (int i=0 ;i<ab.length-1 ;i++ ) {
         String aux=ab[i];
         if(!aux.equals(ab[i+1])){
         temporal1[n++]=aux;
         }
         }
         temporal1[n++]=ab[ab.length-1];
         
         for (int j=0;j<temporal1.length;j++ ) {
         if(temporal1[j]!=null){
         cont++;
         }
         }
         String[] arregloDefinitvo=new String[cont];
         int m=0;
         for (int k=0;k<temporal1.length ;k++ ) {
         if(temporal1[k]!=null){
         arregloDefinitvo[m]=temporal1[k];
         m++;
         }
         }
      return arregloDefinitvo;  
  }  
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a1={"a","b","c"};
        String[] a2={"a","e"};  
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unionSinRpetirDatos(a1,a2)));

}
}
```

salida [a,b,c,e]

Comment: una mayor explicación siempre es buena, 1. por que se nota que el Autor aún esta en el proceso de aprendizaje y 2. Las respuestas son para todos y no solo para pocas personas :D

Comment: :o entiendo,bien pues lo primero que hice fue unir los valores de ambos arreglos en uno solo con System.arraycopy,pero segun lo planteado no debe ir datos repetidos,entonces en el primer (For) elimino el dato repetido y lo almaceno en un arreglo temporal,sim embargo ese dato es reemplazado con un null,,en el segundo for cuento los valores que son diferentes a nul para generar un arreglo definitvo en el cual solo almaceno los datos unicos de ambos arreglos sin que me aparezca null gracias al tercer for

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/477401/edit) tu respuesta agregando la explicación